# Nuxt 3: Cannot find module 'C:/Program Files/nodejs/node_modules/@nuxt/devtools/module.cjs'

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt3

I run

```
npm run dev
```

error:

```
ERROR  Cannot start nuxt:  Cannot find module 'C:/Program Files/nodejs/node_modules/@nuxt/devtools/module.cjs'
Require stack:
- P:\random\project-directory\index.js

  Require stack:
  - index.js
  at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1090:15)
  at Function.resolve (node:internal/modules/helpers:125:19)
  at Function._resolve [as resolve] (node_modules\.pnpm\jiti@1.18.2\node_modules\jiti\dist\jiti.js:1:241025)
  at resolveModule (/P:/random/project-directory/node_modules/.pnpm/@nuxt+kit@3.3.3/node_modules/@nuxt/kit/dist/index.mjs:260:29)
  at normalizeModule (/P:/random/project-directory/node_modules/.pnpm/@nuxt+kit@3.3.3/node_modules/@nuxt/kit/dist/index.mjs:469:18)
  at installModule (/P:/random/project-directory/node_modules/.pnpm/@nuxt+kit@3.3.3/node_modules/@nuxt/kit/dist/index.mjs:451:47)
  at initNuxt (/P:/random/project-directory/node_modules/.pnpm/nuxt@3.3.3_eslint@8.34.0_typescript@4.9.5/node_modules/nuxt/dist/index.mjs:2477:13)
  at async load (/P:/random/project-directory/node_modules/.pnpm/nuxi@3.3.3/node_modules/nuxi/dist/chunks/dev.mjs:6824:9)
  at async Object.invoke (/P:/random/project-directory/node_modules/.pnpm/nuxi@3.3.3/node_modules/nuxi/dist/chunks/dev.mjs:6874:5)
  at async _main (/P:/random/project-directory/node_modules/.pnpm/nuxi@3.3.3/node_modules/nuxi/dist/cli.mjs:49:20)
```

Nuxt version: 3.3.3
Node version: 19 (Also tried other versions)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but the problem was only on my pc and got fixed by:

```
npm i -g @nuxt/devtools
```

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter issues with your Nuxt.js application on Windows, please follow these steps for troubleshooting:

Locate the .nuxtrc file in the following directory

> C:\Users\username\

Remove the .nuxtrc file from the directory.

Perform a fresh installation of Nuxt.js dependencies by running the following command in your project directory:

> npm install

If the issue persists, update the Nuxt.js devtools and enable it in the nuxt.config.js file. Run the following commands:

> npm i -g @nuxt/devtools

Then, ensure that the devtools are enabled in your nuxt.config.js file.